# bmi function returns Nan in prompt input but ok in assigned value

Tags: javascript, function

Please help noob here: whats wrong with this why it returns Nan if I input it on prompt, but if I placed the value in bmiCalculator(60,2) it returns 15

```
function bmiCalculator (weight, height) {
    prompt("Enter your weight in kg: " , weight);
    prompt("Enter your height m square: " , height);
    bmi=0; weight=0; height=0;
    bmi = weight/(height * height);
    if (bmi >= 0 && bmi < 18.5){
        value="Underweight";
    }else 
    if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 24.9){
        value="NORMAL";
    }else 
    if (bmi >= 24.9 && bmi <= 29.9){
        value="OVERWEIGHT";
    }
    else 
    if (bmi >= 29.9 && bmi <= 34.9){
        value="OBESE";
    }
    else if (bmi <= 35)
    {
        value="EXTREMELY OBESE";
    }
        interpretation = alert("Your BMI is " + bmi + " Therefore you are " + value );    
        return interpretation;
    }
        bmiCalculator();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few variables that are not being set properly.

First, remove the parameters from your function, since you are setting the height and weight via a prompt.

```js
function bmiCalculator() {
    let weight = prompt("Enter your weight in kg: ");
    let height = prompt("Enter your height m square: ");
```

Then, you need to declare `value`:

```js
let value = '';
```

Here's the updated code below:

```js
function bmiCalculator() {
    let weight = prompt("Enter your weight in kg: ");
    let height = prompt("Enter your height m square: ");
    let bmi = 0;
    let value;
    bmi = weight / (height * height);
    if (bmi >= 0 && bmi < 18.5) {
        value = "Underweight";
    } else
        if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 24.9) {
            value = "NORMAL";
        } else
            if (bmi >= 24.9 && bmi <= 29.9) {
                value = "OVERWEIGHT";
            }
            else
                if (bmi >= 29.9 && bmi <= 34.9) {
                    value = "OBESE";
                }
                else if (bmi <= 35) {
                    value = "EXTREMELY OBESE";
                }
    interpretation = alert("Your BMI is " + bmi + " Therefore you are " + value);
    return interpretation;
}
bmiCalculator();
```